# Subo pagina php via FTP mas a página não sai do cache do servidor

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet, cache

Estou com o seguinte problema.. tenho um website com paginas em php, javascripts.. tudo funcionando bem..

Porém precisei fazer uma simples alteração no código html de uma pagina php.. fiz o upload do arquivo via FTP, substituindo o arquivo anterior.. só que apesar de estar com o arquivo correto no servidor, todos os browsers exibem a versão antiga da pagina.. já fiz todos os procedimentos de limpeza do cache da maquina.. inclusive já deletei a pagina do servidor para ver se dava erro, mas ela ainda é exibida como se nada tivesse acontecido.. existe algum cache em algum lugar que não consigo identificar.. dentro do cpanel não existe nenhuma opção de cache...

Alguém já possou por isso? Alguma ideia?

Comment: Já verificou duas vezes se não está mexendo nos arquivos errados? Acontece...

Comment: Já passei por esse tipo de problema e era um cache no servidor da minha rede. Para contornar o problema adicionei uma query string a url e consegui acessar o arquivo novo. `seusite.com.br/?a=1`

Comment: Tente acessar sua página em modo privado no navegador. Se ainda assim aparecer a página antiga, entre em contato com seu serviço de hospedagem. Se aparecer a página nova, limpe o cache do seu navegador (ctrl + shft + del).